# glClear() crashes GLFW when including GLAD

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw, glad

When I started I used the GLFW example code:

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

When running this it gives me a black screen titled "Hello world" which is exactly what I want. But by simply adding GLAD:

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

...and giving window hints:

```cpp
//Specify the OpenGL versions we're using
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Suddenly it tells me the window failed to initialize.

But by simply adding this:

```cpp
#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif
```

...it allows the window to initialize but crashes when `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` is called and it gives me the error

```
'./Voxel\ Game' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

I know this because when I remove that line it works, it just doesn't clear the screen.

This is the full code I have now in case the error is somewhere else in there:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HIEGHT 480

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    //Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit()) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initalize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    //Specify the OpenGL versions we're using
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif


    //Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HIEGHT, "Voxel Game", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    //Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //Loop until the user closes the window
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        //Render here
        //glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        //Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not initializing `glad`, add `gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress);` after `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` and check it returns OK.

In general, there is no OpenGL library apart from some old OpenGL1.1 stuff (in Windows at least), all those GL calls are implemented in the graphics drivers directly, GLAD library just defines a lot of function pointers and wraps them in nicer macros. Then during initialization, it will dynamically load the functions from the drivers present on the machine. Hence the need to generate GLAD for specific OpenGL version.
So if you get segfaults on some GL calls, a good guess is some of those functions were not found, maybe because they are not supported on the HW or because you did not setup GLAD/GLFW correctly.

Comment: More detailed info here: https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/context_guide.html#context_glext_auto